# Solve system of linear equations $Mp_1 = q_1 \\ Mp_2 = q_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to solve a system of linear equations where $p_1,p_2,q_1,q_2$ are two dimensional vectors and $M$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix.

$$Mp_1  = q_1 \\ Mp_2 = q_2$$

If all the variables were scalars I would solve for $M$ in the first equation and put it into the second equation. But how would I solve for $M$ in the first equation in this case?

Comment: What is the unknown in your equation?

Comment: @mrsamy Sorry for late reply. The unknown is $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to solve for M in terms of the coefficients of $p_1,p_2,q_1$ and $q_2$. Write

$M = \begin{pmatrix} a &b\\ c &d\end{pmatrix}$,

$p_1 = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \end{pmatrix}$,
$p_2 = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{pmatrix}$,
$q_1 = \begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \end{pmatrix}$,
and $q_2 = \begin{pmatrix} d_1 \\ d_2 \end{pmatrix}$,

Then your two equations become:

$\begin{pmatrix} aa_1 +ba_2\\ ca_1+da_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{pmatrix}$

and

$\begin{pmatrix} ac_1 +bc_2\\ cc_1+dc_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} d_1 \\ d_2 \end{pmatrix}$

respectively

Then you have four equations in the four unknowns a,b,c, and d (two vectors, or matrices more generally, are equal iff they have the same respective entries), so you can solve for them in terms of the coefficients of $p_1,p_2,q_1$ and $q_2$.

However, if you want to solve for the coefficients of M in terms of less variables, I can't really guarantee that can happen and/or will have a unique solution with how the problem is set up.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thank you! Studied linear algebra some time ago, so forgot this is how it's actually done.